# Import Customers To Magento via csv

Tags: magento

I'm trying to import customers into magento with a csv file, using Magento built in customer importer.

It's working OK (customers name, email and password goes into database), but the customers billing and shipping addresses are not.

Here's my csv header:

```
'id', '_website', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password_hash',   'billing_firstname', 'billing_lastname', 'billing_company', 'billing_postcode', 'billing_city', 'billing_street1', 'billing_telephone', 'billing_country', 'billing_region', 'shipping_firstname', 'shipping_lastname', 'shipping_company', 'shipping_postcode', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_street1', 'shipping_telephone', 'shipping_country', 'shipping_region', 'is_subscribed', 'group_id', 'dob'
```

I also tried to put these tags into header, but still nothing.

```
'postcode', 'city', 'street1', 'telephone', 'country', 'region',
```

If anyone had this problem and know how to do this, please help,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: please also post first few row values under these attributes to better know the problem.

Comment: 1111 | base | Test | User | test.user@mail.com | 005d05de29487ec44cd07bd9d757d4e1 | Company | Name | | 1234 | City | Street 1 | 123456789 | Country | |

and all the shipping values are empty, thanks

Comment: if the shipping values are empty, i believe you have the delimiters there?

Comment: you can even export your customers and look the format to make sure you are doing it correct. btw, do you get any error or simply billing & shipping data are empty?

Comment: yes, there are only the delimeters

Comment: I don't have any error, Magento just not add those values (but email, firstname and lastname is ok, and I can log in with the user)

Answer (score 9):

OK, I found a solution to do this:

Go to Magento admin->System->Import/Export->**Dataflow profiles**.
*(NOT to Magento admin->System->Import/Export->Import!)*

Then, select profile: Import Customers (or create if it not exists).

I set the Store value in Profile information box to 'Default store view'.
Then, upload Your csv, and run the profile.

It worked for me and goes every value into magento database correctly - shipping and billing addresses too.

Here is my CSV header:

```
id  website firstname   lastname    email   password_hash   billing_firstname   billing_lastname    billing_company billing_postcode    billing_city    billing_street1 billing_telephone   billing_country billing_region  shipping_firstname  shipping_lastname   shipping_company    shipping_postcode   shipping_city   shipping_street1    shipping_telephone  shipping_country    shipping_region is_subscribed   group   group_id    dob
```

I don't know if group_id is required or not, but you must have a group column (I set 'General' value for it.)

I found it a little buggy, so don't panic if everything are set correct and You get an error message like: 'required column website not set' - or similar, I refreshed the Import Dataflow page, run the profile again, and it worked - of course You set everything correctly.

Hope it helps,

Comment: `group_id` IS required as a field in your header row and a value of `1` is `General` by default. `group` is not required as a field.

Answer (score 1):

The "Group_id" is going to cause a problem. The correct header is group. ( I have seen some examples of select statements that are using "Group_id" and I believe they do not know how to escape reserved words in MYSQL.

If you put the default value of General in the Group column the import should be OK

Comment: hi .. is it possible to import customer by csv through cron task. so i dont need to manually upload the csv ?

Answer (score 0):

We can have all the information regarding a customer into the csv.  The fields that are not compulsary can be left blank.

Headers are as follows:

```
website,email,group_id,disable_auto_group_change,firstname,lastname,password_hash,prefix,middlename,suffix,taxvat,billing_prefix,billing_firstname,billing_middlename,billing_lastname,billing_suffix,billing_street_full,billing_street1,billing_street2,billing_street3,billing_street4,billing_street5,billing_street6,billing_street7,billing_street8,billing_city,billing_region,billing_country,billing_postcode,billing_telephone,billing_company,billing_fax,shipping_prefix,shipping_firstname,shipping_middlename,shipping_lastname,shipping_suffix,shipping_street_full,shipping_street1,shipping_street2,shipping_street3,shipping_street4,shipping_street5,shipping_street6,shipping_street7,shipping_street8,shipping_city,shipping_region,shipping_country,shipping_postcode,shipping_telephone,shipping_company,shipping_fax,created_in,is_subscribed,group
```

Hope this helps.